# If $E$ is not compact then any image of $E$ by a continuous 1-1 map is not compact.

Tags: general-topology

If $E$ is not compact then any image of $E$ by a continuous 1-1 map is not compact.

First I was going to prove it by assuming otherwise, saying let there is some open cover for $E$ which doesnot have any finite subcover for $E$ then then assume $f(E)$ is compact then it has finite subcover comes from $E$ but we dont know $f$ is open or not.

Then I try to analyse the problem more but I stuck because I realy dont understand what "any image of $E$ by a continuous 1-1 map is not compact." really means?

Any hint and explanation the above sentence?

Comment: To formalize what this means, you simply have to name, and quantify, the objects that are hidden in the statement: "If $E$ is not compact then for any topological space $X$ and any continuous 1-1 function $f : E \to X$, the image $f(E) \subset X$ is not compact in the subspace topology". So, is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not correct; take any infinite set $A$ and let $X$ be $A$ endowed with the discrete topology and $Y$ the space with the trivial topology. Then the map $X\to Y$, $x\mapsto x$ is continuous, 1-1, $X$ is not compact but $Y$ is.
Other examples: Take $f:[0,2\pi)\to S^1, x\mapsto e^{ix}$, or the function [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986137/if-lim-x-to-a-f-leftx-right-l-then-does-lim-x-to-l-f-1-leftx/3986141#3986141).

Comment: My edit was an extreme nit-pick, to replace the comma after "correct" with a semi-colon, which is used to represent an implied, but not stated, conjunction.....+1

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ has the discrete topology and is infinite (so non-compact), *any* function on $E$ is continuous, so we can map it to a compact set $f[E]$ via a continuous function that we can choose to be 1-1 if so desired. So counterexamples abound.